# Prefill Gmail Username and Password

Tags: php, forms, automation, gmail

**Is it possible to pre-fill the Password inputbox of gmail?**
i can prefill the email by using

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?Email=email@example.com
```

is it possible to prefill the username and password similar to remember me function of a checkbox? and if possible log the user in as well?

Comment: It's not possible, because it negates the purpose of a password

Comment: then is it possible to make it prefill the form, the simillar way when you click a remember me checkbox?

Comment: What a terrible idea. I think you've have a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/220891).

Comment: @Sammitch why would it be a terrible idea so i can consider making another approach?

Comment: How are you going to know a persons password to their email? You really should not ask for that type of information from a person.

Comment: actually i have some email here that i want another person to use but i don't want him to know the password.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you explain, then perhaps we can come up with alternative solutions. I'm not trying to be rough, but I think that there may be other ways to do this. :)

Comment: Well if you are planning to put it in the url then you wont be hiding anything from them. All they would have to do is hover.

Comment: That is why i am also asking if it is possible to prefill the form if not from the URL then similar to remember me checkbox that automatically puts the user and pass to the form